# Google Analytics - sending custom dimension, but some are missing

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to record in GA a custom session id, and the serial number of a page visit in a session (so the first page a user visits gets 1, second page gets 2, etc.). Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
function genGuid(){
return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
        });
}

if (typeof $.cookie('optltcs_session') == 'undefined'){
    var guid = genGuid();
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('optltcs_session', guid, {path: '/', expires: date});
    $.cookie('optltcs_viewed', 0, {path: '/'});
}
else{
    if (typeof $.cookie('optltcs_viewed') == 'undefined'){
        $.cookie('optltcs_viewed', 0, {path: '/'});
    }
    else{
        old = $.cookie('optltcs_viewed', Number);
        $.cookie('optltcs_viewed', old+1, {path: '/'});
    }
}
ga('set', 'dimension1', $.cookie('optltcs_session'));
ga('set', 'dimension4', $.cookie('optltcs_viewed'));
ga('send', 'event', 'PIDSID', 'send', {'nonInteraction': 1});
})
```

It's working except that some of the 'dimension4' variables are missing - in a session I can see page view no. 0, and then no. 6, and 1-5 are missing. What could be the cause? How do I debug this (the local debugger on the browser shows this is working fine)?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any luck on finding a solution?

Comment: my likely suspect is GA's limitation of not sending more than 10 events over a five second period (http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=195). I'm going to record the events in my own server to make sure the code is actually running,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, GA engine will overwrite the old dimension4 with the new dimension4 sent in the context of a session.

My solution is to send just the session id to GA, and send the page id-s (dimension4) to my own server, so I can later join the two datasets to get a complete picture.